# Custom image with rotation in activity indicator for iPhone application in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I want my company logo as in activity indicator with rotation in my iPhone application. I am working on swift. Can anyone suggest me some third party library other than **SVProgressHUD** as this is not providing any custom image rotation.

If someone can suggest an custom code then also it will be appreciated.

Comment: So you want just to have your company logo rotating on 360 degrees ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
final class MyActivityIndicator: UIImageView {

    override func startAnimating() {
        isHidden = false
        rotate()
    }

    override func stopAnimating() {
        isHidden = true
        removeRotation()
    }

    private func rotate() {
        let rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotation.toValue = NSNumber(value: Double.pi * 2)
        rotation.duration = 1
        rotation.isCumulative = true
        rotation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        layer.add(rotation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }

    private func removeRotation() {
        layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let activityIndicator = MyActivityIndicator(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
activityIndicator.image = UIImage(named: "TOU IMAGE")
view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

Comment: You should remove UIActivityIndicatorView subclassing, because it adds the native ai behind the imageView.

Comment: This also works if you add a `UIImageView` via a storyboard, and set the `UIImageView` class to the `MyActivityIndicator` class. You can also set the image right on the storyboard.